# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll occurring in Visual Studio designer.cs

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2013

I seem to be having a problem with my project and I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution.

I am receiving the error message below when InitializeComponent() is called on one of my forms. It seems to be related to two picture boxes when they are setting the image.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

The exception is thrown on the following lines in my form.designer.cs file:

```
this.pictureBox3.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox3.Image")));
```

and

```
this.pictureBox2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox2.Image")));
```

These are the line of code that are generated when I point the picture box to a local resource image but when I change the image to point at resources the same error occurs. The following are the lines of code when pointing to a resource.

```
this.pictureBox2.Image = global::TemperatureManagementSystem.Properties.Resources.BuildingPlan;
this.pictureBox3.Image = global::TemperatureManagementSystem.Properties.Resources.Temperature_ledge;
```

When setting breakpoints on these two line, the application seems to loop around them infinitely setting them to null and setting the image again. Here is the code for the two picture box controls in OverviewForm.Designer.cs:

```
this.pictureBox3.Image = global::TemperatureManagementSystem.Properties.Resources.Temperature_ledge;
this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 419);
this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(471, 71);
this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 1;
this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;

this.pictureBox2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
this.pictureBox2.Image = global::TemperatureManagementSystem.Properties.Resources.BuildingPlan;
this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 24);
this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1250, 368);
this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 0;
this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
```

Below is the stack trace for the exception.

```
>   TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.overviewForm.InitializeComponent() Line 579 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.overviewForm.overviewForm() Line 21 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 17 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.ReviewForm.ReviewForm() Line 18 C#
TemperatureManagementSystem.exe!TemperatureManagementSystem.homeForm.homeForm() Line 16 C#
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening or a possible solution to it? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  Just showing us the individual lines of code is not enough.  You need to show us where those lines are called.  Are you certain that `((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox2.Image")))` is returning a non null value?  I think resources are case sensitive.  Have you double checked the spelling/case of the resource name?  Included the namespace (if necessary), etc. ?

Comment: Most of the code in the designer is automatically generated when I design the form visually and I am pointing each picture box to the correct resource so the naming should be correct.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Okay, so I managed to get it working. Not really sure what the problem was but I created a new form and copied over the controls. It worked immediately.